# is there a trick giving access to HLSL constants like access members of a struct in HLSL shadercode

Tags: hlsl

I reorganized a lot of my HLSL shader code, but I still could not solve the following problem

```
// e.g. the include file of global usable constants

static const uint gc_diffuse_lambert = 1;
 
static const uint gc_material_opaque = 5;
```

in my shadercode i want to access them like

`if ( diffuse_type == globals.gc_diffuse_lambert) { // do something }`

I know how to set a constantbuffer definition in HLSL shadercode that does exactly what i want (i use them this way all the time), but a constantbuffer must be initialized from CPU side and uploaded what i want to avoid.

I search a method or trick that lets me define the constants as part of a “pseudo struct”
`something.member` or `something::member`

maybe i can "bind" the consts to a structure or a class or something else

thanks for all answers